# как в архитектуре FSD использовать next js 14 с app route?

Tags: reactjs, архитектура, nextjs, next.js

На официальном сайте FSD прочитал, что нужно папку app вынести из nameproject/src в nameproject/...

Что должно храниться в папке nameproject/src/app ? Если страницы, которые импортируются компонентами из nameproject/page, находятся теперь получается как route в nameproject/app/...

Что хранить в src/app в nextjs 14 при app route. Понятно что в папку app в верхнем каталоге отправляем page. А что делать с src/app, куда девать провайдер стейт менеджера? Пример файла src/app

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={appRouter()} />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, делаем полную копию папки апп некста, в папке апп фсд, очищаем все файлы в папке некста и из них экспортируем все из папки фсд.

Например дефолтный файл `page.tsx` в папке `app` некста (которая должна лежать в корне проекта) у меня выглядит так:

```
export { Home as default } from "@/app/page";
```

А все дефолтное содержимое этого файла теперь лежит в папке `src/app`.

Тем самым вроде получается соблюсти фсд, так как весь проект настраивается теперь из фсд app папки, и next не ругается
В общем в папке `app` проекта у тебя просто соблюдается необходимая вложенность для маршрутизации и запуска проекта, но внутри файлов просто экспортируешь по дефолту все из `src/`.

Comment: Да и прикол в том что папка src/app осталась пустая. Я туда скинул провайдеры разные чтобы не пустовала. Потом ещё проблема с неймингом возможно будет поэтому лучше папку src/page переименовать в папку src/page-view например